# How to query PostGIS for the XYZ tiles covered by features?

Tags: postgis, tiles

I have a `feature` table in PostgreSQL and I need to calculate the XYZ tiles that the queried features encompass.

So my query would look something like this:

```sql
SELECT getTiles(geom, min_zoom, max_zoom)
FROM feature
```

And I want it to return a XYZ array for each tile:

```sql
[167,367,10],[159,368,10],[160,368,10],[161,368,10],[162,368,10]...
```

How can I calculate the tile XYZ values like this pseudocode `getTiles`? I've looked through the PostGIS documentation and [Mapbox's Postgis utils](https://github.com/mapbox/postgis-vt-util) but haven't found examples of this. I feel like such a function probably already exists in some applications.

Comment: The reverse of ST_TileEnvelope() does not exist. You have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenStreetMap wiki has [code examples to convert between longitude/latitude and tile coordinates](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#PostgreSQL) in many languages.

One could combine these functions with `generate_series` to iterate over all tiles in the bounding box.

Note that for irregular geometries it stupidly iterates over all tiles in the bounding box, even if they are not touched by the geometries.

```sql
-- Source: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#PostgreSQL
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lon2tile(lon DOUBLE PRECISION, zoom INTEGER)
  RETURNS INTEGER AS
$BODY$
    SELECT FLOOR( (lon + 180) / 360 * (1 << zoom) )::INTEGER;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lat2tile(lat double precision, zoom integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
    SELECT floor( (1.0 - ln(tan(radians(lat)) + 1.0 / cos(radians(lat))) / pi()) / 2.0 * (1 << zoom) )::integer;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getTiles(extent box2d, min_zoom integer, max_zoom integer)
  RETURNS TABLE (x integer, y integer, z integer) AS
$BODY$
    SELECT x, y, z
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                lon2tile(ST_XMin(extent), zoom) AS x_min,
                lon2tile(ST_XMax(extent), zoom) AS x_max,
                lat2tile(ST_YMax(extent), zoom) AS y_min,
                lat2tile(ST_YMin(extent), zoom) AS y_max,
                zoom AS z
            FROM
                generate_series(min_zoom, max_zoom) zoom
            GROUP BY zoom
        ) minmax_per_zoom
        CROSS JOIN
        generate_series(x_min, x_max) x
        CROSS JOIN
        generate_series (y_min, y_max) y
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE SQL
;
```

Call the function like this:

```sql
SELECT
  x, y, z
FROM
  getTiles(
    (SELECT ST_Extent(ST_Transform(geom, 4326)) FROM your_table),
    /* min zoom */ 5, /* max zoom */ 19)
;
```

The extent must be in SRID 4326. As the [Box2D](https://postgis.net/docs/Box2D.html) data type doesn’t support SRID type modified, I don’t think there’s a way to enforce this in the function.

Also I haven’t found a way to move the `ST_Extent` inside the function and still operate on the whole table.